# Indication of remaining time to format an external HDD

Tags: hard-drive, disk-format

Is there any way to see how long it will still take to format an external hard drive? I used Disk Utility to do so, and it now just tells me "Formatting...", without any indication of the progress. I chose quick format, so expected it to take minutes. But it already took >20 min, for a 2 TB drive.

[image: Disk Utility screenshot]

Comment: Does FAT even support 2 TB partitions?

Comment: MS-DOS (FAT): Use for Windows volumes that are 32 GB or less. ExFAT: Use for Windows volumes that are over 32 GB. Lifted from the [Apple Support Page](https://support.apple.com/guide/disk-utility/file-system-formats-dsku19ed921c/mac). Are you creating a volume to use with a Windows partition?

Comment: @IconDaemon no, I am trying to format a disk to be able to check it with Western Digital Drive Utilities (it doesn't pass extended SMART on my Synology).